# Classes in C++ compilation error

Tags: c++, file, class, header

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? I tried really hard before posting. Thank you so much.

I am getting

```
"In file included from familyRunner.cpp:7:0:
   familytree.h:22:40: error: expected identifier before ‘-’ token
    QuadraticHashTable<Human> hash_table(-1, 50000);" error.
```

---

```
class FamilyTree
{
public:
  FamilyTree(Family *families, int familyCount);
  void runQueries(Query *queries, Person *answers, int queryCount);
  QuadraticHashTable<Human> hash_table(-1, 50000);
};
```

Comment: sorry I had trouble posting it! It is up now

Comment: Are you missing an include or forward declaration for `QuadraticHashTable<>`?

Comment: I added the #include at the top.
#include "QuadraticProbing.h"
#include "familyRunner.h"

Comment: Do you guys have any other thoughts? I really appreciate it. I'm stuck

Comment: Are you including the `-std` option to gcc to tell it to enable C++11 mode? You'll need it for that `hash_table` in-class initialiser.

Comment: @AndyBrown I don't think that in class initializers can use the parenthesed format anyway: it must be a brace or equal initializer.  (In cases like this, I wouldn't bother with the in class initializer anyway; it exposes too much information in the header.)

Answer (score 0):

this line doesn't look right:

```
QuadraticHashTable<Human> hash_table(-1, 50000);
```

You can't do inline initialise with (), you have to use {} or = , for example:

```
QuadraticHashTable<Human> hash_table {-1, 50000};
```

Or you can initialize it in your cpp file where FamilyTree constructor is defined.